# FB share with callback

Tags: javascript, facebook

im trying to implement a facebook share function with a callback.

I have found this example script

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
function fb_share() {
    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
        link: "https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/",
        picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
        caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
    }, function( response ) {
        if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
            console.log( response );
            // ajax call to save response
          $.post( 'http://www.example.com/', { 'meta': response }, function( result ) {
                console.log( result );
            }, 'json' );
        }
    } );


}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class='share-btn'>click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However it doesn't seem to work, although some people say it works for them. When I click the button nothing happens. Is there an error somewhere? Or maybe someone could direct me to another sample. Would be very grateful!! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a few things. I took a quick look at the Facebook JS SDK docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0), and it seems like you're missing a source for the SDK and an FB init method with your app credentials. For example:

```
function fb_share() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.0'
  });
  FB.ui( {
    method: 'feed',
    name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
    link: "https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/",
    picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
    caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
}, function( response ) {
    if ( response !== null && typeof response.post_id !== 'undefined' ) {
        console.log( response );
        // ajax call to save response
      $.post( 'http://www.example.com/', { 'meta': response }, function( result ) {
            console.log( result );
        }, 'json' );
    }
});
```

}

Here is a JSFiddle with all that included http://jsfiddle.net/bn7F7/.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thanks so much! It does work now, but there's a slight poblem. Only I can use the share feature... other get an error saying: an error occured.  I checked the URLs in facebook settings, everything seems to be fine. Why is it only me who can use the share feature?

Comment: Sorry, stupid me... The app wasn't made public. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @Boomish Which URL should I put in link and $.post I used my localhost URL and its showing the error.